# One single point wrongly triangulated (calibration with a 4 points board)

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, triangulation

I'm filming with 6 RGB cameras a scene that I want to reconstruct in 3D, kind of like in the following picture. And **I forgot to take a calibration chessboard**. So I used a blank rectangle board instead and filmed it, as I would film a regular chessboard.
[image: 3D reconstruction]

**First step, calibration** --> OK.
I obviously couldn't use `cv2.findChessboardCorners`, so I made a small program that would allow me to click and store the location of each 4 corners. I calibrated from these 4 points for about 10-15 frames as a test.
*Tl;Dr*: It seemed to work great.

**Next step, triangulation. --> NOT OK**
I use direct linear transform (DLT) to triangulate my points from all 6 cameras.
*Tl;Dr*: It's not working so well.

- Image and world coordinates are connected this way: [image: formula],
- which can be written [image: formula].
- A singular value decomposition (SVD) gives [image: formula]

3 of the 4 points are correctly triangulated, but the blue one that should lie on the origin has a wrong x coordinate.
[image: triangulation fails]

**WHY?**
Why only one point, and why only the x coordinate?
Does it have anything to do with the fact that I calibrate from a 4 points board?
*If so, can you explain; and if not, what else could it be?*
**Update:** I tried for an other frame while the board is somewhere else, and the triangulation is fine.
So there is the mystery: some points are randomly triangulated wrong (or at least the one at the origin), while most of the others are fine. *Again, why?*

My guess is that it comes from the triangulation rather than from the calibration, and that there is no connexion with my sloppy calibration process.
One common issue I came across is the ambiguity in the solutions found by DLT. Indeed, solving AQ = 0 or solving AC C-¹Q gives the same solution. [See page 46 here](https://filebox.ece.vt.edu/%7Ejbhuang/teaching/ece5554-4554/fa17/lectures/Lecture_15_StructureFromMotion.pdf). But I don't know what to do about it.

---

I'm now fairly sure this is not a calibration issue but I don't want to delete this part of my post.

- I used `ret, K, D, R, T = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, imSize, None, None)`.  It worked seamlessly, and the points where
  perfectly reprojected on my original image with
  `cv2.projectPoints(objpoints, R, T, K, D)`.
- I computed my projection matrix P as [image: formula], and `R, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(R)`
- How is it that I get a solution while I have only 4 points per image?
  Wouldn't I need 6 of them at least? 
   We have [image: formula].
  We
  can solve P by SVD under the form [image: formula] 
  This is 2
  equations per point, for 11 independent unknown P parameters. So 4
  points make 8 equations, which shouldn't be enough. 
  And yet
  `cv2.calibrateCamera` still gives a solution. It must be using
  another method? I came across Perspective-n-Point (PnP), is it what
  opencv uses? In which case, is it directly optimizing K, R, and T and
  thus needs less points?
  I could artificially add a few points
  to get more than the 4 corner points of my board (for example, the
  centers of the edges, or the center of the rectangle). But is it
  really the issue?
- When calibrating, one needs to decompose the projection matrix into
  intrinsic and extrinsic matrices. But this decomposition is not
  unique and has 4 solutions. [See there section 'I'm seeing
  double'](http://ksimek.github.io/2012/08/14/decompose/) and [Chapt.21 of Hartley&Zisserman about Cheirality](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/multiple-view-geometry-in-computer-vision/cheirality/2269D936A5BB233CBB0E9567C000F9C6)
  for more information.  
  It is not my issue since my camera points
  are correctly reprojected to the image plane and my cameras are
  correctly set up on my 3D scene.

Comment: I didnt understand everything, but if you observe vertically flipped points: Have a look at opencv coordinate space. They use a 3D coordinate system where positive y coordinate is going from top to bottom (because it's same for image coordinates) and positive z goes from camera to the depth (different from openGL for example).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I actually took that into account and I believe it's not my problem. And now that I checked this link, I'm about sure it's not a calibration issue, since 
- my cameras points are correctly reprojected on the image plane
- my cameras are correctly set up (see 2nd pic)

It's probably rather a triangulation issue.

http://ksimek.github.io/2012/08/14/decompose/

Comment: I edited my original post to make it clearer (see bullet points before the spoilers)

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite understand what you are asking, it is rather vague. However, I think you are miscalculating your projection matrix.
if I'm not mistaken, you will surely define 4 3D points representing your rectangle in real world space in this way for example:

```py
pt_3D = [[ 0  0  0]
         [ 0  1  0]
         [ 1  1  0]
         [ 1  0  0]]
```

you will then retrieve the corresponding 2D points (in order) of each image, and generate two vectors as follows:

```py
objpoints = [pt_3D,      pt_3D,      ....] # N times
imgpoints = [pt_2D_img1, pt_3D_img2, ....] # N times ( N images )
```

You can then calibrate your camera and recover the camera poses as well as the projection matrices as follows:

```py
    ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, imSize, None, None)
    cv2.projectPoints(objpoints, rvecs, tvecs, K, dist)
    

    for rvec, tvec in zip(rvecs, tvecs):
        Rt, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(rvec)
        R = Rt.T
        T = - R @ tvec
        pose_Matrix       = np.vstack(( np.hstack((R,T)) , [0, 0, 0, 1])) ( transformation matrix == camera pose )
        Projection_Matrix = K @ TransformationMatrix.T[:3, :4]
```

You don't have to apply the DLT or the triangulation (all is done in the `cv2.calibrateCamera ()` function, and the 3D points remain what you define yourself

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit?
Are you showing me how to go from *Qcam = R Qworld + T* to *Qworld = R' Qcam + T* ?
I didn't code it exactly like that (by the way, you made me learn about the @ operator that I didn't know about, thanks!) but I did something similar.

I don't think it's my problem since the calibrated camera points where perfectly reprojected on my original image.

Comment: No problem and thanks already! I edited my original post to make it clearer (see bullet points before the spoilers)

Comment: I modified my explanation hoping to have answered your question because I did not really understand what you are trying to do